# Why React component only renders one item in array once but iterates through all items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase

I am stuck with a problem where I am building a blog with React and storing my blog posts in Firebase.

The problem is that it goes through all items correctly in the useeffect function but when I want to render my items on the page it only shows one, the last item in my array.

Here is my code:

```
export default function Blog(props){
    const [blogPost, showBlogPost] = useState(null);
    const [blogPosts, setBlogPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
            db.collection('blogposts').get().then(posts => {
                console.log(posts.docs.length);
                posts.docs.forEach(post => {
                    blogPosts.push(post.data());
                    console.log(post.data());
                    
                    setBlogPosts([post.data()]);
                    console.log(blogPosts);
            })  
        })
    }, [])

    console.log(blogPosts);

    return(
        <div>  
            {CreateBlogPost()}
                {blogPosts.map(post => {                  
                        switch (blogPost) {
                            case post.id:
                                return( <BlogPost goBack={() => showBlogPost(null)} id={post.id} date={post.date} heading={post.heading} introduction={post.introduction} entry={post.entry} /> );   
                            case null: 
                                        return(
                                            <div> 
                                                 <ul className="blog-posts">
                                                     <div className="blog-post-item" onClick={() => showBlogPost(post.id)}>
                                                             <img src={Image}  alt="Girl in a jacket" width="400" height="200" />
                                                             <h1 id="blog-post-heading">{post.heading}</h1>      
                                                         <div className="time-stamp">
                                                             <p id="blog-post-publish-date"><ClockIcon /> <time dateTime={post.date}>{post.date}</time></p>
                                                         </div>
                                                     </div>
                                                 </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        );           
                            default: return null
                        }
                })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is where I console log my array after pushing all my data from Firebase in my array which works fine:

[image]

The code iterates through my code fine only within the useEffect function but when I console log blogPosts state array outside useEffect and try to render my array, it only renders the last item on the page.
[image]

Can someone please help me with this issue and guide me on how I should go forward here.
All help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three problems:

- Don't mutate state in React - you shouldn't be using `.push` on stateful arrays
- The `setBlogPosts([post.data()]);` only sets the new state array to a single item
- You're calling `setBlogPosts` for every element in the array, when you should only be calling it once, after processing all `posts.docs`

Use

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('blogposts').get().then(posts => {
        const newBlogPosts = [];
        posts.docs.forEach(post => {
            newBlogPosts.push(post.data());
        })
        setBlogPosts(newBlogPosts);
    })
    // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response and help. It solved my problem. Thanks again.